# Adding header (or any element) to div moves div down page about 500px

Tags: html, css

Can't wrap my head around it. Doesn't happen with smaller resolutions.
 The question I am asking is how do I prevent this from happen.

Example

https://jsfiddle.net/eddietal2/qgLvsx2v/

CSS:

```
 .svg-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 25px 25px 120px 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -99;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="svg-wrapper">
        <h1>Hello</h1>  // Element that causes all the problems. 
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Day 1</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly do you want to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to keep the element in the same place when I add an element to it. When I add an element to the box, it moves down about 500px. Ideally, I'd like for that not to happen

Answer (score 0):

It was behaving this way because of the *display* being set to **inline-block**. The answer was adding:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

ugghhh so simple.